# Equivalent definitions of reflecting brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

In what follows, $D$ is a precompact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with say $C^3$ boundary, $\eta(a)$ is the inward unit normal vector to the boundary at $a$.I'm trying to prove the equivalence of the following statements:

1) Let $X_t$ be the continuous strong Markov process on filtrated space $(C^0([0,1],D), \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}_t)$  with transition density function given by the fundamental solution of the heat equation with Neumann conditions:

$$\partial_t p(t,x,y) = \Delta_x p(t,x,y) , (x,y) \in D \times \bar{D} $$
$$\partial_{\eta} p(t,x,y) = 0 , (x,y) \in \partial D \times \bar{D}$$
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} p(t,x,y) = 0 ,(x,y) \in \bar{D} \times \bar{D}$$

2) Define a measure $\mathbb{P}^x$ on the filtrated space $(C^0([0,1],D), \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}_t)$ which satisfies $\mathbb{P}^x(X_0 = x) = 1$ and for any $f \in C^2 (\bar{D})$ with $\partial_{\eta}f \geq 0$, 
$$M_{f}(X_t) = f(X_t) - f(X_0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \Delta f(X_s) ds$$

is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-submartingale.

I have a feeling that this should just be a elementary (albeit possibly long and tedious) computation, but I don't quite know how to start. Could I get some hints as to how to go about it, or maybe something along the lines of how to connect $p$ and $\mathbb{E}[f(X_t) | \sigma(X_s) ]$? I'm not asking for the full-blown computation, but maybe an outline with the details left out? At this point, I'd take any help anyone is willing to give me.

Thanks!

Comment: the Neumann conditions are for points on the boundary?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit lazy on equation, I'll edit right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look on the article of Stroock and Varadhan diffusion processes with boundary conditions (1971). The idea is to consider the local time on the boundary $\xi$ (an increasing measure) and prove that.

$$\phi(X(t)) - \int_0^t \chi_{G} \Delta \phi(X(s))\, ds - \int_0^t \langle \nabla \phi, \eta\rangle \, d\xi $$

Is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale.

Then note that $- \int_0^t \langle \nabla \phi, \eta\rangle \, d\xi =  A_t$ is a decreasing process and $\int_0^t \chi_{G} \Delta \phi(X(s))\, ds  = \int_0^t \Delta \phi(X(s))\, ds $ since the process spend time zero at the boundary. All this is the subject of the article and requires lengthy  calculations.

Once you have this, It will be easy to note that

$$\phi(X(t)) - \int_0^t  \Delta \phi(X(s))\, ds$$

is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-submartingale

**remark:** You don't need to worry about $\phi(X_0)$ since it is a constant $\Bbb{P}(\phi(X_0) = \phi(x))=1$

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll read the article!